# my custom module is not visible at /admin/modules

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have been working through the guidance available at:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules

I added my custom module to my composer.json, like so:

```
composer config repositories.mygit \
  '{ "type": "vcs", 
     "url": "git@git.mydomain.com:cf_supporters_for_drupal.git",
     "ssh2": { "username": "git", 
               "privkey_file": "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa",
               "pubkey_file": "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" } }'

composer require ymd/cf_supporters_for_drupal
```

in the path with my composer.json file, I run:

```
drupal$ find . -name cf_supporters_for_drupal
./vendor/ymd/cf_supporters_for_drupal
```

browsing to it, using `git status` and `git log` I have determined that I have the newest version installed.

And yet, I see no evidence in the /admin/modules path that the module is available to me.  I'm curious about how I might begin to debug this issue.  Can anyone provide any guidance beyond what I already see at:  https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file#debugging ???

```
~/sandbox/cf_supporters_for_drupal $ cat cf_supporters_for_drupal.info.yml 
name: CF Supporters for Drupal Module
description: Exposes the cf_supporters_mojo application on a drupal web site.
package: Custom
type: module
version: 1.0
core: 8.x
configure: cf_supporters_for_drupal.settings

~/sandbox/cf_supporters_for_drupal $ cat composer.json 
{
    "name": "ymd/cf_supporters_for_drupal",
    "description": "A drupal module to expose cf_supporters_mojo",
    "type": "module",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later"
}

~/sandbox/cf_supporters_for_drupal $ tree . 
.
├── cf_supporters_for_drupal.info.yml
├── cf_supporters_for_drupal.links.menu.yml
├── cf_supporters_for_drupal.routing.yml
├── composer.json
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── src
    └── Controller
        └── CFSupportersForDrupalController.php

2 directories, 7 files
```

**UPDATE #1:**

2pha, in a comment below, suggests I need to put this code in a modules folder, rather than simply in the vendors folder.  My questions back in 2pha's direction are:

I assume I want to put it perhaps in `web/modules/custom` ???  Is that right?  How is it, using the composer config cli tool (I need to script this as much as possible), would I make that happen?

Comment: your module must be in the modules folder for drupal to detect it

Comment: I assume I want to put it perhaps in `web/modules/custom` ???  Is that right?  How is it, using the composer config cli tool (I need to script this as much as possible), would I make that happen?

Comment: Did you start the project by using [drupal/recommended-project](https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project)?  If so, you will see it have installer paths set in the composer file, specifically different "types". `type:drupal-module` installs to `web/modules/contrib/{$name}`, type `type:drupal-custom-module` installs to `web/modules/custom/{$name}`. This "type" is set in your modules composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you, 2pha!

Late last night, I found documented here:
https://github.com/composer/installers

that composer has built in support for fourteen drupal-specific 'types', including: 'drupal-custom-module'.  I have not (yet) found a way using `composer config` to manipulate extra.installer-paths hash in composer.json.  But doing so manually as you suggest above, resulted in exposing my module on the `/admin/modules` and the `/admin/config` pages.  For the moment that is close enough that I have now turned my attention to creating a configuration page for my module.